# Why is AlMg3 called aluminum alloy?

Tags: metal, metallurgy, alloy

In AlMg3, magnesium atoms outnumber aluminum atoms by a factor of three. In terms of mass, the ratio of aluminium to magnesium is a mere $27.0 / (3\times24.3) = 0.37$.

*Shouldn't AlMg3 be better called magnesium alloy?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**AlMg3 is not the chemical formula of the alloy**, it's the [product name for a wrought alloy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_alloy#Wrought_alloys). Its [technical sheet](http://www.stella-welding.com/st/AlMg3.pdf) specifies the following composition:

> ***Product name***
> AlMg3
>
> ***Class of product***
> Al-Mg alloy for MIG/TIG welding.
>
> ***Corresponding standards***
> DIN 1732, SG-AlMg3, AWS A5.10, ER 5754
>
> ***Nominal composition (weight %)***
> Al: Bal. Si: 0.4 Mg: 3 Mn: 0.5

Thus, **the 3 in the product name refers to 3 % (in weight) of magnesium.**